# archlinux grub lvm - /usr/bin/grub-probe: ошибка: не найдет диск (Решено)

Tags: grub, archlinux, криптография, lvm

Устанавливаю на чистый бук archlinux с luks.

Все делаю спокойно и непринужденно:

```
Все ставлю как обычно, иду в chroot

pacman -S sudo grub-bios os-prober

sed -i -e 's/# %wheel ALL=(ALL) ALL/%wheel ALL=(ALL) ALL/' /etc/sudoers

Вставляю в Хуках файла /etc/mkinitcpio.conf: encrypt и lvm2 перед filesystems

mkinitcpio -p linux

sed -i -e 's/use_lvmetad = 1/use_lvmetad = 0/' /etc/lvm/lvm.conf
systemctl enable lvm2-lvmetad.service
systemctl enable lvm2-lvmetad.socket

grub-install --recheck /dev/sda
sed -i -e 's|GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""|GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="cryptdevice=/dev/sda2:main"|' /etc/default/grub
grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

Вываливается ошибка:

```
[root@archiso /]# grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
Генерируется файл настройки grub …
Найден образ linux: /boot/vmlinuz-linux
Found initrd image(s) in /boot: initramfs-linux.img
Found fallback initrd image(s) in /boot: initramfs-linux-fallback.img
/usr/bin/grub-probe: ошибка: диск «lvmid/XmgzMS-K5fu-W0XR-X2pa-UBHg- 0Its-jXvKL9/05gmdw-q9Wc-2aYm-n76Y-B9OW-ppcP-fvjSN1» не найден.
```

завершено

При этом

```
[root@archiso /]# vgdisplay | grep UUID
VG UUID               XmgzMS-K5fu-W0XR-X2pa-UBHg-0Its-jXvKL9
```

Есть уже совпадение и

```
[root@archiso /]# lvdisplay | grep -E "(Path|Name|UUID)" 
  LV Path                /dev/main/root
  LV Name                root
  VG Name                main
  LV UUID                05gmdw-q9Wc-2aYm-n76Y-B9OW-ppcP-fvjSN1
  LV Path                /dev/main/swap
  LV Name                swap
  VG Name                main
  LV UUID                kv7eYn-WZDe-YuTz-Sw9i-cIdn-uMQm-hqanQl
  LV Path                /dev/main/home
  LV Name                home
  VG Name                main
  LV UUID                kVam6w-zyUs-pemv-ffL0-2qNU-A34N-lBNOMh
```

То есть сами диски/разделы на месте, а вот grub  не видит их...

Как быть, подскажите пожалуйста?

Добавлю.

Проблема была решена.
В начале зашифровал раздел

```
cryptsetup --verbose --cipher aes-xts-plain64 --key-size 512 --hash sha512 --iter-time 5000 --use-random  luksFormat /dev/sda
```

После разных попыток все исправить, перешаифровал раздел без ключа --use-random

```
cryptsetup --verbose --cipher aes-xts-plain64 --key-size 512 --hash sha512 --iter-time 5000  luksFormat /dev/sda
```

После этого, все установилось и номально встало.
Будте внимательны)

Comment: Точно - спасибо)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема была решена. В начале зашифровал раздел

```
cryptsetup --verbose --cipher aes-xts-plain64 --key-size 512 --hash sha512 --iter-time 5000 --use-random  luksFormat /dev/sda
```

После разных попыток все исправить, перешифровал раздел без ключа --use-random

```
cryptsetup --verbose --cipher aes-xts-plain64 --key-size 512 --hash sha512 --iter-time 5000  luksFormat /dev/sda
```

После этого, все установилось и номально встало. Будте внимательны)